# C# Discord.NET: Why this ban module prevents anybody from interacting with my bot?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am creating a Discord bot using the Discord.NET API. I have been implementing commands and modules to my bot for a while now, and I am attempting to add a ban command to my bot. I made the command so you have to have a role named "Bot Admin". Here is the code that I am using that seems to be causing the problem:

```
public class Ban : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("ban")]
    [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers)]
    public async Task banUser([Remainder]SocketGuildUser usertobehammered, string banre)
    {
        var rUser = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
        var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Bot Admin");

        if (rUser.Roles.Contains(role))
        {
            await ReplyAsync($"User {usertobehammered.Mention} has been banned.");
            await Context.Guild.AddBanAsync(usertobehammered, 0, banre);
        }

        else
        {
            await ReplyAsync(":no_entry_sign: You need the Bot Admin role to do that!");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but with this here my bot will come online when I run it like normal, but attempting to run any commands will do nothing. Deleting the class allows users to use commands again.

Anybody know what the problem is here?

EDIT: Still don't know the cause of this, but I do have another command that uses the variables "rUser" and "role" which are also used here, but I don't believe that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, it was actually really simple. I just had to swap the SocketGuildUser and the string around so it would look like this:

```
[Command("ban")]
[RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers)]
public async Task banUser(string banre, [Remainder]SocketGuildUser usertobehammered)
```

Rather than the original which looks like this:

```
[Command("ban")]
[RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers)]
public async Task banUser([Remainder]SocketGuildUser usertobehammered, string banre)
```

I think the problem was that I believe Remainder puts anything after the first word into the next argument, which would make it so a SocketGuildUser is being put into a string, which without using something like "SocketGuildUser.mention" apparently makes the bot not respond to commands. People, please don't make this silly mistake I made. :$